# Append variable to each dictionary in list

Tags: ansible

I have got multiple files.
One of them:

```yaml
kind: Deployment
name: pr1-dep
---
kind: Ingress
name: pr1-ing
```

My Ansible role:

```yaml
- name: "Cat command result to list of dictionary"
  set_fact:
      objects: '{{ objects | default([]) + [ object ] | flatten }}'
  vars:
    object: { 'items': "{{ item.stdout | from_yaml_all | list }}", 'filename': "{{ item.item.dest }}" }
  loop: "{{ cat.results }}"
```

The results above role:

```yaml
- filename: srv.yaml
  items: [
    {kind: Deployment, name: pr1-dep},
    {kind: Ingress, name: pr1-ing}
  ]
```

I would like to have filename in each dictionary. Expected result:

```yaml
- [
    {kind: Deployment, name: pr1-dep, filename: srv.yaml},
    {kind: Ingress, name: pr1-ing, filename: srv.yaml}
  ]
```

How could I achieve this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`map` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map) to apply the [`combine` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) to each list element with your single key dict containing the file name.

```yaml
- name: "Cat command result to list of dictionary"
  set_fact:
      objects: '{{ objects | default([]) + [ object ] | flatten }}'
  vars:
    file_addition:
      filename: "{{ item.item.dest }}"
    object:
      items: "{{ item.stdout | from_yaml_all | list | map('combine', file_addition) }}"
  loop: "{{ cat.results }}"
```

Forward note: Using `cat` in `shell/command` to get a yaml file content is a bad practice in ansible. You can use the [`file` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_lookup.html) if the file is local or the [`slurp` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/slurp_module.html) if you need to read a remote file.